# Quote field name and table name in Advantage database SQL

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am working on a legacy system developed with Advantage Database 8.1, I need to run SQL, like:

"SELECT CODETEST.DESC FROM CODETEST"

This SQL won't run at .NET due to the "CODETEST.DESC" name which is belong to SQL reserved keyword "DESC", I think to quote the "CODETEST.DESC", for example, in MySQL, we can use 'CODETEST'.'DESC' (I changed ` to ' here) to avoid that.

I read Advantage Database Help but can't find how to do so, it's a legacy system, and the database structure won't be changed. So is there any way to quote the table and field name in Advantage SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, here [Use of Non-Standard Characters in Names](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/advantage_sql/sql_functionality/use_of_non-standard_characters_in_names.htm), its simple by `[CODETEST].[DESC]`

> Double quotes and [] (brackets) are used to delimit identifiers that
>   contain non-alphanumeric characters or that start with numbers. For
>   example, if a database contains a table name or column name that
>   starts with a number, contains spaces, or that has non-alphanumeric
>   characters, the application must enclose the name in double quotes or
>   [] (brackets) (e.g., "3D", "Contact Date", "l/c", [Full Name]). Also,
>   full path names or table names that include extensions must be
>   enclosed in double quotes or [] (brackets) (e.g., "x:\pathname\table",
>   "\server\volume\path\table", "table.abc", "..\otherdir\table").